# Distributed compile with bitbake

Tags: build, distributed, distcc, bitbake

Do you got any idea how to build an  oe project with distributed bitbake compile?
I've thinked about distcc.

```
export PATH=~/distcc/bin:$PATH
make -jn CC=linux-gcc
```

make will call linux-gcc from my path which points to distcc.
distcc will schedule the tasks to all known hosts.
-jn will create n6 instances of make.
It works fine.
But now I want to use distcc with bitbake.
I know how to use -jn with bitbake.
Just use `export PARALLEL_MAKE=-jn`

But how to use export `PATH=~/distcc/bin:$PATH` with bitbake.
The `distcc/bin` MUST stand in front of the `$PATH`.
But bitbake will place the `$PATH_prepend` (placed in org.openembedded.dev/conf/bitbake.conf) in front of the `$PATH`.

Or someone got another tool for better way of distributed building with bitbake?

Comment: export command will add the given path to $PATH variable and will be active in that session. But I am not clear about your problem. Could you please explain your problem

Comment: The problem is I just know how to use PARALLEL_MAKE ,but when it comes to bitbake ,who calls make at last,I got no idear how to config it to work as  PARALLEL_MAKE  way.

Answer (score 18):

Try Icecream: https://github.com/icecc/icecream/blob/master/README.md

> Like distcc, Icecream takes compile jobs from a build and distributes it among remote machines allowing a parallel build. But unlike distcc, Icecream uses a central server that dynamically schedules the compile jobs to the fastest free server.

Both OpenEmbedded and Yocto Project support Icecream. See https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/plain/meta/classes/icecc.bbclass

Install Icecream, then add the following to your **site.conf** or **local.conf**

```
INHERIT += "icecc"

# This value overrides PARALLEL_MAKE when ICECC is enabled
# This would enable icecc for local and cross
ICECC_PARALLEL_MAKE = "-j 24"
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more BitBake-ish way of invoking builds with parallelism is to edit local.conf and un-comment BB_NUMBER_THREADS and PARALLEL_MAKE and set their values to twice the number of cores that you have.  Now, whenever you invoke BitBake, it will use these values.

Comment: I've tried BB_NUMBER_THREADS ways ,but it dosen't got a great improve in single machine.Seem that the OS has limit the make threads

Comment: Increasing to a certain level is giving a negative impact