# Methods for speeding up build time in a project using bitbake?

Tags: python, build, embedded, openembedded, bitbake

I'm working in a project which has many bitbake recipes and takes a lot of time - up to 13 hours in some cases. I am new to bitbake and I'm asking for some way to:

- check what packages take more to build
- check very long dependencies (I have used bitbake -g already)
- check if there are any circular dependencies and how to solve them
- check if there are recipes which aren't used and how to safely remove them

or any suggestions for using any tools for better managing and understanding recipes.

Or any methods/ways for speeding up the build process in general.

Both suggestions and exact techniques are welcomed.

**EDIT date 07/08/2013:**

Found this useful tool for tracking dependencies

https://github.com/scottellis/oe-deptools

Description:

```
./oey.py -h

Usage: ./oey.py [options] [package]

Displays OE build dependencies for a given package or recipe.
Uses the pn-depends.dot file for its raw data.
Generate a pn-depends.dot file by running bitbake -g <recipe>.

Options:
-h      Show this help message and exit
-v      Show error messages such as recursive dependencies
-r      Show reverse dependencies, i.e. packages dependent on package
-f      Flat output instead of default tree output
-d <depth>      Maximum depth to follow dependencies, default and max is 10
-s      Show child package dependencies that are already listed
        as direct parent dependencies.

Provide a package name from the generated pn-depends.dot file.
Run the program without a package name to get a list of
available package names.
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is a very broad question!

First, here is a summary on how to inspect your build performance
and dependencies when using the openembedded/yocto project. This answers the first part of the question.

### What packages take more time to build?

Use the **buildstats** with the **pybootchartgui** tool produce a build chart.

Details:

Set `USER_CLASSES += "buildstats"` in your `$BUILDIR/conf/local.conf`
file. This will dump detailed performance data in
`$BUILDDIR/tmp/buildstats/<DATE>`. Next use the `pybootchartgui.py` script (in
`poky/scripts/pybootchartgui`) to generate the chart. This will help you
localize possible bottlenecks in the build. Of course, if you have a
lot of recipes to bake, your chart will be huge. To remove some noise
use the `-m MINTIME` command line option.

For example:

```
poky/scripts/pybootchartgui/pybootchartgui.py -m 600 $BUILDDIR/tmp/buildstats/201312310904
```

will only display tasks (do_compile, do_fetch, etc.) that take longer
than 10 minutes (600 seconds) to run.

### How to check for package dependencies?

To explore the dependencies of a particular package use the depexp
utility. For example, to explore the dependencies of eglibc use:

```
bitbake -g -u depexp eglibc
```

This will give a better understanding of what each recipe depends on
at both run and compile time.

### How to check if there are any circular dependencies and how to solve them?

bitbake automatically detects circular dependencies and prints an error message when such a thing happens.
The error message contains the name of the packages causing this circular dependency.

### How to check if there are recipes which aren't used and how to safely remove them?

bitbake calculates dependencies automatically and won't build
packages which aren't needed by your target. If you find some unwanted packages in your image and you wish to remove them:

1. use `bitbake -g -u depexp <TARGET>` to inspect how the package gets pulled in
2. modify the needed recipes in your layer (by creating a bbappend for example) to eliminate the dependency manually

### Improving overall build performance

Finally, some tips on how to improve the overall build performance. This answers the second part of the question.

- Clean up your dependencies (`bitbake -g -u depexp <TARGET>` is your friend). Building less stuff takes less time.
- bitbake can automatically cache the build outputs and use it for
  future builds, this cache is called the "shared-state cache" and is
  controlled with the `SSTATE_DIR` variable in your `local.conf`.
- Set the `BB_NUMBER_THREADS` and `PARALLEL_MAKE` variables in your `local.conf` to match your
  machine's resources. These variables control how many tasks are run
  in parallel and how many processes 'make' should run in parallel (`-j`
  option) respectively.
- Put the 'build' directory on its own disk.
- Use the ext4 filesystem **without** journaling and with these mount
  options: `noatime,barrier=0,commit=6000`. **WARNING**: This makes your
  hdd unreliable in case of power losses. Do not store anything of
  value on this hdd.
- building images with `-dev` and/or `-dbg` packages increases the
  do_rootfs task time considerably. Make sure you enable them (see
  `EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES` in your `local.conf`) **only** when needed.
- openembedded and yocto both support [icecream](http://en.opensuse.org/Icecream) (distributed compile). See the icecc class and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472175/distributed-compile-with-bitbake).
- Buy a faster machine ;)

References:

[Yocto Build Performance Wiki](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Build_Performance)

[Bitbake GUI tools](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/BitBake/GUI)

Comment: pybootchartgui is alright, but I find that [ElectricInsight produces bitbake visualizations that are much easier to understand and use](http://www.electric-cloud.com/blog/2013/05/10/yoctoopenembedded-bitbake-build-visualization/) _(disclaimer: I develop ElectricInsight)_

Comment: `depexp` has been renamed to `taskexp` in newer releases: `bitbake -g -u taskexp <TARGET>`

Answer (score 4):

I've tried the [distributed compile way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472175/distributed-compile-with-bitbake) years ago ,but the server environment config is not that flexible for CI agent work ,and the build is not that suit for muti-people .

I've tried analyse with the build time with [buildstats](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Build_Performance) ,
and found **the build time is nearly cost all by compiling the 3-rd party opensource components, which I didn't modify at all**.

So The most simple and effective way is to use "sstate-cache" to avoid unmodified components to build again.

**The way I use in my work is to trade space for time**

> 1. Compile the whole bitbake project ,you could find many  .tgz files under "build/sstate-cache"
> 2. Add and commit all this files to git for tracking the file modification
> 3. Compile the whole project again without clean it
> 4. cd to your "build/sstate-cache"  ,git status and found the files which is modified, delete them and commit to git
> 5. Then clean project without .tgzs under "sstate-cache" , The Trade of space for time is done

The "unmodified" files list could be modified according to  your own project .

**The build time reduce for me is from 1 hour to within 10 minutes**

Hope this would be helpful

Comment: could you explain in high level how does this prevent the compiling of 3rdparty software?

Comment: The oe - bitbake project often contain a build environment tools compile when you first build the whole project. which is wise to treat with the various environment of developers,but for developers ourselves,we do not need to do the tools compile every time .So we could use the sstate-cache, which has cashed the "Tools" and the not modified "3rdparty software" , make time for the "real code" compile.  The idea  came from the second time compile time reduce , tread space to save time

Comment: Not too keen on the idea of storing all those binaries in git... better hope you're using LFS

Comment: You can use `SSTATE_MIRRORS` to store your prebuilt sstate outside of your repo, possibly in a place accessible to multiple people.  The setscene tasks will copy from `SSTATE_MIRRORS` to your local `SSTATE_DIR`.